# SMS not showing up in the actions menu

Tags: sms, clickatell

I have installed and set up the SMS Clickatell extensions and activated the provider on CiviCRM, but SMS doesn't show up in the actions menu of a contact and the batch SMS isn't working.
Do you have any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the user have permission in the CMS? There's one called `CiviCRM: send SMS`. Also the recipient contact has to have a phone of type Mobile for it to show up in the actions menu.

Comment: @Demerit Oh! I forgot of this detail. Now it's working but kinda doesn't, because setting the parameters as in the manual returns: Invalid or missing integration API Key.

Comment: Solved @Demerit thanks to your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to set the contact telephone to "Mobile". Thanks @Demerit.

Comment: yep it only shows if phone is set to mobile. caught me out before now too